# At the second coming, will Jesus descend in the same body or will he be reborn again?

Tags: christology, second-coming, reincarnation

All of us know that Jesus had ascended to God the father after he had resurrected, we know that he will come again at the end of time to judge the people and found the kingdom of God on earth.

The question is, will he descend as an adult man as he ascended to God the father, or will he be reborn again as an infant in a new incarnation?.

Note: there are many who claimed to be incarnations or reincarnations of Jesus, some of them belong to new Christian denominations, look: [Wikipedia List of people claimed to be Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_claimed_to_be_Jesus)

Esoteric Christianity like Liberal Catholic Church adopts reincarnation and oneness of god who is both transcendent and immanent and accept Tritheism as three persons in that one God,i.e: the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit are manifestations of that one transcendental immanent God. Look: [The Liberal Catholic Church](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.thelccusa.org/about/doctrine.html&ved=2ahUKEwiJqtDln9vmAhVaBGMBHVuACIgQFjAVegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3tmC-K73qW9T0pMn8NF4yE&cshid=1577636090716) and  [Liberal Catholic Church (Wikipedia)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Catholic_Church&ved=2ahUKEwiJqtDln9vmAhVaBGMBHVuACIgQFjATegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1jVuej_N56fVnUqmJKBsJ5&cshid=1577637685926)

I would like answers to be biblically based, it's preferred to be by scholars of Christianity, especially of orthodox Christianity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102684/discussion-on-question-by-salah-at-the-second-coming-will-jesus-descend-in-the).

Answer (score 2):

*At the second coming, Jesus will descend or he will reborn again?*

The biblical answer is Jesus will descend on His Second Coming just like when He ascended with clouds.

> **"For the Lord himself will descend from heaven, with a cry of command, with the archangel's call, and with the sound of the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise first."**(1Thessalonians4:16)
>
> “Look, he is coming with the clouds,”
>
> and “every eye will see him,
>
> even those who pierced him”;
>
> and all peoples on earth “will mourn because of him.”
>
> So shall it be! Amen. (Revelation 1:7)

*The question is, will he descend as adult man as he ascended to God the father or will he reborn again as an infant in new incarnation?.*

**The biblical answer is NO.** The scriptures does not teaches reincarnation.

> ***"It is appointed for men to die once."***(Heberews9:27)

And the Catechism of the Catholic Church teaches the following;

> 1013 *Death is the end of man's earthly pilgrimage, of the time of grace and mercy which God offers him so as to work out his earthly life in keeping with the divine plan, and to decide his ultimate destiny. When "the single course of our earthly life" is completed,586 we shall not return to other earthly lives: "It is appointed for men to die once."587 There is no "reincarnation" after death.*

To put more clarity, why Jesus will not be reborn again is, the Second Coming of Christ speak of His coming as the Just Judge. The key is the word Parousia.

For all the bible verses and apologetic explanation please see the link below;

[**The Parousia: Christ's Second Coming**](http://www.catholicapologetics.org/ap090500.htm)

Comment: I am afraid that what apostle Paul said about the second coming is what he thought about the two men in white garments.

Comment: @salah There is no reason to be afraid of, St.Paul is guided by the Holy Spirit in his teachings, therefore it is the Truth. Either you believe his writings & teachings or not it is up to you.

Comment: I accept the whole Bible but allegorically, metaphorically not literally. I apply the herminutics and logic in exegesis of the holy books. How do you accept that a man is obsessed with 2000 unclean spirits. Do you believe in obsession?!.

Comment: Could you tell me how to shade the quotes with yellow colour.

Comment: Use the symbol >immediately before the first word of a quote.

Comment: After finishing the quote how to finish the shade to start a new phrases without shade.

Answer (score 1):

**At the second coming, will Jesus descend from heaven or will he be reborn again?**

The Scriptures are very clear on this subject. Jesus, at the Second Coming, will return in the same manner that he ascended into heaven.

> 9And when he had said these things, while they looked on, he was raised up: and a cloud received him out of their sight. 10And while they were beholding him going up to heaven, behold two men stood by them in white garments. 11Who also said: Ye men of Galilee, why stand you looking up to heaven? **This Jesus who is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come as you have seen him going into heaven.** - [Acts 1: 9-11](https://biblehub.com/drb/acts/1.htm)

[image: Jesus' ascension to Heaven depicted by John Singleton Copley in Ascension (1775)]

[Jesus' ascension to Heaven depicted by John Singleton Copley in Ascension (1775)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_of_Jesus#/media/File%3AJesus_ascending_to_heaven.jpg)

> **Two men** - From the raiment of these "men," and the nature of their message, it seems clear that they were angelic beings, who were sent to meet and comfort the disciples on this occasion. They appeared in human form, and Luke describes them as they appeared. Angels are not infrequently called people. Luke 24:4, "two men stood by them in shining garments," etc. Compare John 20:12; Matthew 28:5. As two angels are mentioned only as addressing the apostles after the resurrection of Jesus John 20:12; Luke 24:4, it is no unnatural supposition that these were the same who had been designated to the honorable office of bearing witness to his resurrection, and of giving them all the information about that resurrection, and of his ascension, which their circumstances needed.
>
> **In white apparel** - Angels are commonly represented as clothed in white. See the John 20:12 note; Matthew 28:3 note; Mark 16:5 note. It is an emblem of purity; and the worshippers of heaven are represented as clothed in this manner. Revelation 3:4, "they shall walk with me in white"; Revelation 3:5, "He that overcometh shall be clothed in white raiment"; Revelation 4:4; Revelation 7:9, Revelation 7:13-14. - [And while they looked steadfastly toward heaven as he went up, behold, two men stood by them in white apparel](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/acts/1-10.htm)

What more needs to be said?

> It is the traditional view of Roman Catholics and Orthodox Christians, preserved from the early Church, that the Second Coming will be a sudden and unmistakable incident, like "a flash of lightning".[Mt 24:27] They hold the general view that Jesus will not spend any time on the earth in ministry or preaching, but come to judge mankind.They also agree that the ministry of the Antichrist will take place right before the Second Coming.
>
> Many Christian denominations consider this second coming of Christ to be the final and eternal judgment by God of the people in every nation resulting in the glorification of some and the punishment of others. The concept is found in all the Canonical gospels, particularly the Gospel of Matthew. - [Second Coming (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming)

Comment: the two men stood by them in white garments, how did you know they are angels, as in the photo, how did you know they are saying a message from God?. Why didn't Jesus tell them that message by himself?. What about the Christian mysticism?.

Comment: I am afraid that my be delusion and illusion. Not the eye witnessing of the desciples but what they thought about the two men they thought they were angels.

Comment: The question is answered. You can ask a second question if you want.

Comment: I want to use some phrases in a thick font, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

JESUS SECOND COMING ~ part 1

The Bible verses I'm using, which can help us understand Jesus's Second Coming, are:

> Revelation1:7 "Look! He comes with the clouds of heaven and everyone
>   will see him, even those who pierced him. And all the nations will
>   mourn for him..";
>
> Luke24:39 "Look at my hands and my feet ((showing the nail-wound
>   piercings)). You can really see that it's me...I am not a ghost..((and
>   he ate)) a piece of cooked fish";
>
> Luke24:51 "while he was blessing them, he left them and was taken up
>   to heaven".

The fact that he ascended bodily back to God his Father with his nail-wounds intact suggests that he will also return to the earth (in order to renew it and reunite it with heaven, as Paradise regained) bearing those same prominent scars - and so every human, whether they trusted Jesus in their life or didn't, will see that he is indeed the Jesus who died, nailed to a wooden cross, who rose back to life, and ascended back to heaven.

In Hebrews 9:27 God tells us that "each person is destined to die once and after that the judgement; so also Christ died once for ALL time, as a sacrifice, to take away the sins of many people.

He will come again, not to deal ((then)) with our sins ((then it will be too late for any human to start a relationship with Jesus, God)) but to bring salvation to all who are eagerly waiting for him".

It is helpful for us to remember that Jesus, and Heavenly Father, and Holy-Spirit are the 3 Persons of the ONE God. We humans have limited, finite minds, and cannot properly understand how we have ONE God, but that he is 3 Persons. God has no difficulty understanding this, thankfully ~ but God himself tells us in Genesis1:26 "let US create humans in OUR own image, to be like OURSELVES.."

Notice that God refers to himself in the plural. The three Persons of God had already, in all of eternity past, been in relationship with each other. This is crucial information, because it also gives humans God's pattern for relationship: humans-with-humans, and humans-with-God. Jesus is the second Person in the God-Trinity, and so has always existed, as spirit. He has always been known by many names, as listed in the Old Testament: "Immanuel" in Isaiah7:14, "Redeemer" in Job.

Those are names which describe Jesus's mission. These names alert us to the fact that the Redeemer will rescue Christ-trusting humans from their sin-sickness (hamartia). The angel Gabriel, in the gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke + John, tells Joseph that when Mary's divine Christ-child is born, he is to be called "Jesus". Jesus's names "Christ" and "Messiah" are descriptive titles of Jesus's mission to rescue humans from a likely eternity in hell.   More to come...

Comment: Whoa! Please [edit] this to add some paragraph breaks.